# Why don't lambda functions introduce similar issues as goto statements?

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-function, goto

In my c# book it reads, "The => lambda operator (read as 'goes to')."

I've been wondering for a while what is the difference between a goto and a lambda expression in terms of good coding practice. If goto's are avoided due to the possibility of convoluted code, then couldn't lambda expressions also lead to this same issue? More generally, why am I highly encouraged to use lambda functions, while I am highly discouraged from using goto's? (i.e. I have an ok grasp of why goto's are unpopular, but why aren't lambda functions unpopular for similar reasons?)

My only guess is that lambda functions evaluate and return something, where as we do not know what a goto may go off to do. This at least should make lambda functions easier to test as they fall more in line with the ideas of organized, object-oriented code.

Comment: "goes to" != "goto".  Your last paragraph explains why lambdas are accepted and gotos are not.  "goes to" should probably be translates as "is transformed to" or "results in", while "goto" means "forget the logic and order of this procedure, breka whatever this program is doing and run this line of code NOW.

Comment: Execution doesn't go/jump  anwhere when you write a lambda.  You just define an inline function that will be called (and end) and the specified point. _'goes to'_ is just one way of __pronounicing__ the operator `=>` but what it means it really just a sort of __assignment__!

Comment: "goes to"?! I've never correlated lambdas with "goes to". That's just weird to me.

Answer (score 5):

Just because you "read" `=>` as "goes to" does not mean that it has anything to do with old-school GOTO statements. They are completely different things. I've heard developers alternatively use phrases like "yields", or just "arrow" when they read that symbol aloud.

A GOTO statement gives developers too much freedom to move the execution point to an arbitrary point in code. It tends to introduce bugs because it's hard for developers to keep track of all the possible states that various variables might be in at any given point in time, when the execution is able to jump around arbitrarily.

All functions (including lambda functions) have defined scopes and an execution flow that follows the logic established by the rest of the C# language. Remember that lambda syntax is just "syntax sugar" that maps to a `delegate`/closure, which is basically just a glorified function.

Comment: This should be a comment unless you add WHY they are completely different things.